# Git rebase in developing with an iterative upstream

Tags: git, rebase, upstream

Git `rebase` for me is a good way to get a linear history, but recently I got a little confused of its behavior. The situation is that I have my local repo, my origin repo on GitLab and the read-only upstream repo of my course.

Basically TAs release documentations and codes in upstream repo, I fetch it and merge into my repo, and then finish the lab. It is an iterative process, for the lab2 is released after I finish lab1 and push it into origin. Things confusing happens in this iteration.

After lab3 was released, I rebased `master` (which contains my code for lab1 and lab2) onto `upstream/master`, only to find that my commits were all gathered together at latest location of git history, like:

**lab1-TA-release -> lab2-TA-release -> lab3-TA-release -> lab1-my-code (with rebase time) -> lab2-my-code (with rebase time)**

I think it is commits time that shows the track of my work, so what I'd like to see is a linear history like:

**lab1-TA-release -> lab1-my-code -> lab2-TA-release -> lab2-my-code -> lab3-TA-release**

Is there any way to realize my wish?

-----update-----

For example, now I have finished lab2 and lab3 has been released on `upstream/master`. `lab3-TA-release` is not on my local master (so I cannot simply use `rebase` to resort my `master`). I need to `git rebase upstream/master` first. It is here that `my lab2-my-code` and `lab1-my-code` got gathered together and all refreshed with new time. So the real commit time (when I finished my work) disappear and I got confused.

Is there any way to automatically reserve original time (means the real time) of commits and make it linear?

Comment: Have you tried any git command yet?

Comment: @syohey I tried rebase upstream/master onto master(that is, in the reverse direction), but it seems not right.

Comment: Are there any conflicts between `lab2-TA-release` and `lab1-my-code`?

Comment: Do you have specific instructions on how to handle branches and commits in your local clone ? for example : must the answer to `lab3` be committed on top of the original `lab3-release` commit ?

Comment: @LeGEC no, I just want the history be linear and exactly follows the commits timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The tests I have been made was all in wrong direction. I'd like to answer my own question and give anyone who passes by some information.

Suppose that I have finished lab2 and lab3 has been released on `upstream/master`. `lab3-TA-release` is not on my local master.

The first thing is

```
$ git fetch upstream/master
$ git checkout upstream/master
```

And now `HEAD` is detached, simply run

```
$ git rebase master
```

to `rebase` `upstream/master` onto `master`.

Then it is important to save changes by creating a new temporary branch, for `HEAD` is detached. If you just checkout to other branch, changes are gone.

```
$ git branch temp
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp
```

And the `merge` would be `fast-forward`, things all set.

Then just delete `temp` branch by

```
$ git branch -d temp
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no conflicts between `lab2-TA-release` and `lab1-my-code` commits, you can do `git rebase -i HEAD~4` (It doesn't need to be `4`, but probably 4 in your case.) and simply change the order of the commits.

For example, when you run `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, you should probably see something like this:

```
pick <hash4...> Lab 2 released.
pick <hash3...> Lab 1 finished.
pick <hash2...> Lab 2 finished.
pick <hash1...> Lab 3 released.

# Rebase ...
# ...
```

Then you can simply switch the order by cutting and pasting:

```
pick <hash3...> Lab 1 finished.
pick <hash4...> Lab 2 released.
pick <hash2...> Lab 2 finished.
pick <hash1...> Lab 3 released.

# Rebase ...
# ...
```

I think if you only care about the commit timeline of your local repo, then it should retain the original times commited after reordering.

But, when you are to push the change to your remote repo, you might have to `git push --force` because otherwise you might get asked to `git pull` first before you push the new change, which is probably not what you're wanting because you seem to want your local commit timeline looking straight, not any merging happening in the graph of your commit history?

It's just that when you `git push --force`, it will not change the original times commited locally, but will change the times commited in the remote repo to the time you've pushed at.

Maybe you could try creating a temp branch and test it out to see what it looks like.

```
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git push -u origin temp
$ git rebase -i HEAD~n # Replace n with an appropriate number and reorder the commits. It should be successful if there isn't any conflict.
```

And when you `git status`, you should see the following messages:

```
On branch temp
Your branch and 'origin/temp' have diverged,
and have n and n different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So you `git push --force`, and when you `git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=rfc2822`, you should see a straight commit history with original time stamps.

And you can also look at the commit timeline of your remote repo to see what it looks like.

Comment: that would be `HEAD~4` (or `HEAD~n`), not `HEAD^4` (or `HEAD^n`).

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! So the key thing is first `git fetch upstream` and `git rebase upstream/master`, and then use `interactive rebase` to resort commits on local master? But the real time of original commits (the time when `lab3-TA-release` be created by TAs) would be changed?

Comment: @Kiyoaki Hi! Sorry about the typo earlier! Thanks LeGEC for pointing it out! I updated my answer. I'm sorry if it still doesn't help accomplish what you're wanting..

Comment: @syohey Hi! I think I got you and I know that `force push` is necessary, but the key thing is not about `origin` because it is only an online backup for me. For example, now I have finished lab2 and lab3 has been released but not in my local master (so I cannot simply resort). So I would `git rebase upstream/master` first to have `lab3-TA-release` in, let's say, `master`. It is here that my `lab2-my-code` and `lab1-my-code` got gathered together and all refreshed with new time. So the real commit time (when I finished my work) disappear and I got confused.